# unable to store scraped data into excel file

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, datastore

Hii guys I was scraping this data and my code is working fine but I am not able to understand how to store this scraped data into a excel file and I am getting more confused after looking at others solution and answers

here is my code

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import openpyxl

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

##### Web scraper for infinite scrolling page #####
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/south-delhi-restaurants/fast-food?rating_range=4.0-5.0&category=2")
time.sleep(10)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1
count=0

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
page_sources= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
title=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='sc-jHZirH intUsQ']")

for i in title:
    count += 1  
    name =i.find_element_by_xpath('./div/h4')
    address = i.find_element_by_xpath('./p[1]')

    #data = openpyxl.load_workbook('Bakery.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bakery Restaurants": name,"Address":address})

print(count)
driver.close()
```

this is the main block of code

```
page_sources= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
title=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='sc-jHZirH intUsQ']")

for i in title:
    count += 1  
    name =i.find_element_by_xpath('./div/h4')
    address = i.find_element_by_xpath('./p[1]')

    #data = openpyxl.load_workbook('Bakery.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bakery Restaurants": name,"Address":address})

print(count)
driver.close()
```

please help me out, I am too confused ,any suggestion/solution will be appreciated

Comment: If your data is already in a pandas df - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: i don't know how use pandas in this can you help me please,i have never done this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your scraping is working correctly. You need to store `name` and `address` to the excel

```
# scraping code
#
#
names = []  # Create lists to hold your columns
addresses = [] # Create lists to hold your columns
for i in title:
    count += 1  
    name =i.find_element_by_xpath('./div/h4')
    names.append(name)
    address = i.find_element_by_xpath('./p[1]')
    addresses.append(address)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Addresses': addresses})  # Create a DF with the lists

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Note: Make sure the datatype of the scraped values is string or a type supported by pandas and excel. And not a python object.

Docs: [Insert into DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)
[DataFrame to Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: this is the error i am getting
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/krishan/PycharmProjects/zomato/bakery.py", line 45, in <module>
     with('output.xlsx', 'w+') as op:
 AttributeError: __enter__      what is wrong

Comment: @krishan sorry my bad, I missed the function `open()`. I can't test the code as I don't have the scraping data

Comment: sorry @shoaib30 but it is still not working but I have done it in some other way please check my answer thanks for participating,I really appreciate it

Comment: @krishan I modified my answer with ExcelWriter, and I suppose you have the same. Use it  with `with` or remember to close it, else you would have the file open

Answer (score 0):

this is my attempt and working fine

```
names=[]
addresses=[]

for i in title:
    count += 1
    name =i.find_element_by_xpath('./div/h4').text
    address = i.find_element_by_xpath('./p[1]').text
    names.append(name)
    addresses.append(address)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Addresses': addresses})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```